# Pennylane: creating QNodes for large numbers of circuits that only differ by number of wires

Tags: programming, quantum-circuit, pennylane

Take the following simple quantum function:

```
def my_quantum_function(params, wires=None):

    for i in range(wires):
        random_rot = params[i]
        qml.RY(random_rot, wires=i)
        
    qml.broadcast(qml.CZ, wires=range(wires), pattern="chain")
     
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))
```

Let's say I want to make QNode objects using this function for wires=2 and wires=3. My understanding is that I can either leave the function as it is and write,

```
params = [np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi) for _ in range(wires)]

dev1 = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=2)
circuit1 = qml.QNode(my_quantum_function, dev1)
result1 = circuit1(params, wires=2)

dev2 = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=3)
circuit2 = qml.QNode(my_quantum_function, dev2)
result2 = circuit2(params, wires=3)
```

or, I can make two copies of the function and use the QNode decorator:

```
dev1 = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=2)
dev2 = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=2)

@qml.qnode(dev1)
def circuit1(params):

    wires = 2
    for i in range(wires):
        random_rot = params[i]
        qml.RY(random_rot, wires=i)
        
    qml.broadcast(qml.CZ, wires=range(wires), pattern="chain")
     
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))

@qml.qnode(dev2)
def circuit2(params):

    wires = 3
    for i in range(wires):
        random_rot = params[i]
        qml.RY(random_rot, wires=i)
        
    qml.broadcast(qml.CZ, wires=range(wires), pattern="chain")
     
    return qml.expval(qml.PauliZ(0))

params = [np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi) for _ in range(wires)]
result1 = circuit1(params)
result2 = circuit2(params)
```

Fair enough. But let's say I wanted to create QNode objects using this function for wires=2,3,4,...,20. What is the most idiomatic way to do this? I know QNodes collections is a way to define families of QNodes, but this still requires explicitly defining all $N$ devices you need, which doesn't end up saving any time, as it appears. Right now what I'm doing is using the top function I gave and a for-loop, defining a new device/QNode on each iteration:

```
n_wires = [i+2 for i in range(19)]
for n in n_wires:
    params = [np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi) for _ in range(n)]
    dev = qml.device("default.qubit", wires=n)
    circuit = qml.QNode(my_quantum_function, dev)
    result = circuit(thetas, wires=n)
    ...
    # Do some computations
    ...
```

Using the QNode decorator is the recommended approach, and QNodes can be set to mutable, but I can't find an example in the documentation where you can adjust the number of wires on the fly. Maybe there isn't a more elegant way to do this, but I thought I would ask. Sorry for the long-winded question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received a great answer to my question [here](https://discuss.pennylane.ai/t/creating-qnodes-for-large-numbers-of-circuits-that-only-differ-by-number-of-wires/831?u=ryanhill1), through the Xanadu Discussion Forum:

> I’d say that your approach of having a quantum function that depends
> on the number of wires, creating separate QNodes and devices is a good
> one. PennyLane doesn’t have any further conveniences for such a use
> case, other than creating a `QNodeCollection` which you’ve mentioned.
>
> When considering the exact use case, each of these quantum functions
> would actually be equivalent to running a quantum circuit of size $N=2..20$
> on a quantum device that is capable of simulating exactly $N$ qubits.
>
> The implied alternative to this would have to involve creating a
> single quantum device with 20 qubits, running the quantum circuits one
> by one on that device and resetting the device in between circuit runs
> (can be achieved by calling `dev.reset()`). Both for simulators and
> for hardware devices it can be costly to have unused ancillae
> subsystems. One simulator that could be interesting is [The
> Wavefunction device](https://pennylane-forest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devices/wavefunction.html) from the PennyLane-Forest plugin, which only
> keeps track of the active subsystems in memory.
>
> It could be interesting to see in which cases a tradeoff could be made
> between the two approaches.

Credit to [@antalszava](https://discuss.pennylane.ai/u/antalszava/summary)!